# Join available sizes per product in MySql

Tags: mysql, join

I have 6 tables:

**products**
id
category
active

**product_versions**
id
product_id
color
size_id
active

**sizes**
id
order

**size_content**
id
size_id
name
lang

**product_properties**
id
product_id
property_id

**properties**
id
name

The point is to get the following result:

| product | name | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XS | 1 |
| 1 | S | 2 |
| 1 | M | 3 |
| 1 | L | 4 |
| 1 | XL | 5 |
| 2 | XS | 1 |
| 2 | S | 2 |
| 3 | XS | 1 |
| 3 | S | 2 |
| 3 | M | 3 |

As the product_versions has rows like this:

| product | color | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |

The following SQL works like I need, but I'd like to know, if is it possible to make it faster. Now the result is something about 0,04s at 151 rows.

My idea is to not join all product_versions rows, only one per product+size. I need to know only what sizes are available in what products. For example, if the product has 30 colors and each has 7 available sizes (210 rows per product), I only need to know 7 rows of combination product-size as fast as possible.

In my SQL I'm using `GROUP BY CONCAT(product_versions.product_id,product_versions.size_id)`. If I remove this, there are 3083 rows which need to be grouped. I think, if I didn't have to see all product_versions rows, only one size per product, it should be much faster.

```
SELECT
    products.id AS product,
    size_content.name,
    sizes.id AS size
FROM
    size_content
JOIN sizes ON sizes.id = size_content.size_id
JOIN product_versions ON product_versions.size_id = sizes.id AND product_versions.active = 1
JOIN products ON products.id = product_versions.product_id AND products.active = 1
JOIN product_properties ON product_properties.product_id = products.id
WHERE
    size_content.lang = "en" AND products.category = 2 AND product_properties.property_id IN(14, 83, 106)
GROUP BY
    CONCAT(
        product_versions.product_id,
        product_versions.size_id
    )
ORDER BY
    sizes.order ASC
```

**Explain**

[image]

Do you guys have any idea how to make it better?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these indexes *may* speed up MySQL; I don't know about Postgres:

```
products:  INDEX(category, id,  active)
size_content:  INDEX(lang, size_id,  name)
product_versions:  INDEX(size_id, product_id,  active)
product_versions:  INDEX(product_id, size_id,  active)
product_properties:  INDEX(property_id, product_id)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

There is no advantage in using `CONCAT` in a `GROUP BY`.  Actually, there is likely to be a big disadvantage in doing so -- it prevents the use of an index and forces collecting data in a temp for sorting.  (To be fair, no index is likely to be used by *this* query if you simply say `GROUP BY  product_versions.product_id, product_versions.size_id`.)

Comment: Yes, it helped a little bit. I am on 0,015ms. But the problem is solved in half. It's still shows all combinations of product-sizes (there are f.e. 5 times 1-1 combination). There is the same count of rows without GROUP BY ~3100. I need to know only once if the product has size, doesn't matter in what color and how many. Next, if I select some color in filter (that's what Im working for), it should show only products which has the size in selected color. That's much faster becaouse there are only a few rows ~100. Anyway, thank you for the idea and info that GROUP BY CONCAT doesn't use indexes.

Comment: @brook_river - Instead of one row per size, consider collapsing them into `SELECT ... GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SIZE) ... FROM ...`